# Expanding size of array to growing number of variables

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, realloc

I have read about dynamically expanding arrays in C and lots of answers here, but I cannot find the root of my problem. I try to tokenize using space as separator and store each string in an array, so `"this is string"` becomes `{ "this", "is", "string" }`.

I'm able to do this with predefined array size, but cannot expand it when more words than declared are passed in. Below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEFAULT_SIZE 3 /* default size of an array of words */

// array object
typedef struct {
    char pointer[DEFAULT_SIZE][256];
    int used;
    int size;
} Array;

void createArray(Array *array, int start_size) {
    array->used = 0;
    array->size = start_size;
}

void append(Array *array, char* elem) {
    if (array->used >= array->size) { // if every slot is used, then we expand
        array->size += 2; // expand by 2 slots

        Array *array = malloc(sizeof(Array));
        array = realloc(array, sizeof(array) + 2 * 256);
    }

    strcpy(array->pointer[array->used] , elem); // insert new element
    array->used++; // <-- wrong value here. increment info about used slots
}

char * args_str; // passed string
Array args_list; // expandable array holding words

void parse(char* command) {
    createArray(&args_list, DEFAULT_SIZE);
    args_str = strtok(command, " ");

    while (args_str != NULL) {
        append(&args_list, args_str);
        args_str = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

return ;
}
```

I noticed value of `array->used` gets properly incremented until the array gets expanded. If there are more than 3 items, it goes like 1, 2, 3, 66123 (or other random value here). I suspect this is due to wrong `realloc`, but I

Comment: but I . . . ? what

Comment: Just what do you think a `realloc` of `array` will accomplish? Your struct has a fixed size and contains no pointers (`pointer` in your struct is a 2D array). You can only allocate `sizeof *array` bytes. Adding more storage to it accomplishes nothing. You have no way to address the new memory. You can create an array of struct and benefit from storage for `DEFAULT_SIZE` strings per struct, but you can resize the individual struct.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems you are having is in your fundamental understanding on what you can expand (or use for that matter) with dynamically allocated memory. Your typedeffed struct `Array` is of **fixed-size**. If you allocate for `Array *array`, you cannot thereafter `realloc` the `array`. It will always be `sizeof *array`. Allocating any more memory for it, does no good as it contains no pointer to address any additional memory and would break pointer-arithmetic for the type.

The only thing you can do is allocate for any array of `Array`. But that would be rather cumbersome as each element could only store a max of `DEFAULT_SIZE` tokens.

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish, rather than having your struct contain a fixed-size 2D array `pointer`, you need `pointer` to actually be a *pointer-to-an-array* of `char[256]`. For example, you want:

```
#define DEFAULT_SIZE 3      /* default size of an array of words */
#define TOKEN_SIZE 256

typedef struct {
    char (*pointer)[TOKEN_SIZE];
    int used;
    int size;
} arr;
```

(**note:** C avoids the use of `camelCase` or `PascalCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants.)

Now, you do have something you can resize in `Array` (my `arr` in standard case). You can allocate an instance of `arr` and then allocate for `arr->pointer` (and `realloc` `arr->pointer` when `arr->used >= arr->size`)

Reworking your example, adding proper **validation** of each memory allocation, and using a `realloc` scheme that will `realloc` `arr->pointer` to `2 * arr->size` each time `arr->used >= arr->size`, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DEFAULT_SIZE 3      /* default size of an array of words */
#define TOKEN_SIZE 256

typedef struct {
    char (*pointer)[TOKEN_SIZE];
    int used;
    int size;
} arr;

arr *createArray (int start_size) 
{
    arr *array = malloc (sizeof *array);

    if (!array) {
        perror ("malloc - array");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    array->used = 0;
    array->size = start_size;
    array->pointer = malloc (start_size * sizeof *array->pointer);

    if (!array->pointer) {
        perror ("malloc - array->pointer");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return array;
}

void append (arr *array, char *elem) 
{
    if (array->used >= array->size) {

        void *tmp = realloc (array->pointer, array->size * 2 * sizeof *array->pointer);
        if (!tmp) {
            perror ("realloc - array->pointer");
            return;  /* you should change function type provide success/failure */
        }
        array->pointer = tmp;
        array->size *= 2;       /* update size */
    }

    if (strlen (elem) + 1 < sizeof *array->pointer) {
        strcpy (array->pointer[array->used], elem); // insert new element
        array->used++; // <-- wrong value here. increment info about used slots
    }
    else
        fprintf (stderr, "error: token too long.\n");
}

arr *parse (char* command)
{
    char *args_str;
    arr *args_list = createArray (DEFAULT_SIZE);

    args_str = strtok (command, " ");

    while (args_str != NULL) {
        append (args_list, args_str);
        args_str = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }

    return args_list;
}

/* simple print function */
void prnarr (arr *array)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < array->used; i++)
        printf ("array[%2d] : %s\n", i, array->pointer[i]);
}

/* simple function to free allocated memory */
void freearr (arr *array)
{
    free (array->pointer);
    free (array);
}

int main (void) {

    char str[] = "my dog has fleas my cat has none lucky cat";
    arr *args = parse (str);

    prnarr  (args);
    freearr (args);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arr_struct_arr_of_ptrs
array[ 0] : my
array[ 1] : dog
array[ 2] : has
array[ 3] : fleas
array[ 4] : my
array[ 5] : cat
array[ 6] : has
array[ 7] : none
array[ 8] : lucky
array[ 9] : cat
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/arr_struct_arr_of_ptrs
==9128== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9128== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9128== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9128== Command: ./bin/arr_struct_arr_of_ptrs
==9128==
array[ 0] : my
array[ 1] : dog
array[ 2] : has
array[ 3] : fleas
array[ 4] : my
array[ 5] : cat
array[ 6] : has
array[ 7] : none
array[ 8] : lucky
array[ 9] : cat
==9128==
==9128== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9128==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9128==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 5,392 bytes allocated
==9128==
==9128== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9128==
==9128== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9128== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `realloc` wrong.

```
Array *array = malloc(sizeof(Array));
array = realloc(array, sizeof(array) + 2 * 256);
```

`realloc` is used to resize (either grow or shrink) the amount of dynamically allocated memory. It makes
little sense to first allocate and then reallocate in the next step. Why don't
you allocate enough memory in the first place?

This is how you should reallocate more memory:

```
Array *append(Array *array, char* elem) {
    size_t size;
    if(array == NULL)
        size = 2;
    else if (array->used >= array->size)
        size = array->size + 2;

    Array *tmp = realloc(array, size * sizeof *tmp);
    if(tmp == NULL)
        return NULL;  // telling the caller that something went wrong

    array = tmp;
    array->size = size;


    // I don't understand what you are trying to do here
    // strcpy(array->pointer[array->used] , elem); // insert new element
    // array->used++; // <-- wrong value here. increment info about used slots

    return array;
}
```

I don't know where you get the 256 for `realloc`. Now when calling `append`:

```
Array *tmp = append(array, element);
if(tmp == NULL)
{
    // something went wrong
    // do error handling,
    // do NOT continue
}

array = tmp;
...
```

To be honest, I don't really understand what you are trying to do with the
`Array` structure. `pointer` is an array that cannot be dynamically resized,
because it's size is fixed. Instead you are creating more and more `Array`
objects that already have a 2-dimensional array in them. I don't see the reason
for that.

Anyway, this is what I would use is this:

```
typedef struct {
    char **words;
    size_t size;
    size_t used;
} Array;

Array *createArray(size_t size) {
    Array *array = malloc(sizeof *array);
    if(array == NULL)
        return NULL;

    array->used = 0;
    array->size = size;
    array->words = calloc(size, sizeof *array->words);

    if(array->words == NULL)
    {
        free(array);
        return NULL;
    }

    return array;
}

// it can make grow and shrink the array
int resize_array(Array *array, size_t newsize)
{
    if(array == NULL)
        return 0;

    if(array->size == newsize)
        return 1;

    char **tmp = realloc(array->words, newsize * sizeof *tmp);
    if(tmp == NULL)
        return 0;

    array->words = tmp;

    if(array->size < newsize)
    {
        // setting new fields to 0
        memset(array->words + array->size, 0, newsize - array->size); 
    } else {
        if(array->used > newsize)
            array->used = newsize;
    }

    array->size = newsize;
    return 1;
}

int append(Array *array, char* elem) {
    if(array == NULL || elem == NULL)
        return 0;

    if(array->used >= array->size)
    {
        // adding 2 more spaces
        if(!resize_array(array, array->size + 2))
            return 0;
    }

    array->words[array->used++] = strdup(elem);

    return 1;
}

void free_array(Array *array)
{
    if(array == NULL)
        return;

    for(int i = 0; i < array->size; ++i)
        free(array->words[i]);
    free(array->words);
    free(array);
}
```

Don't forget to free the memory, and please, don't use global variables, that's a bad practice. You have to use
global variables only when they are really necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately, most compilers require that you ask for a warning for reusing the same variable name in different scopes (since it is perfectly "legal"). With gcc, you pass `-Wshadow` to enable the warning. (you will have to check the options for other compilers, although `/Wall` will get it for VS)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin is it? I didn't know that. I tested it with my compiler (GCC) `void foo(int a) { int a=9; }` and I got `error: ‘a’ redeclared as different kind of symbol`. I just used `gcc a.c` without options.

Comment: A redeclaration and shadowing of a declared variable within different scopes is different. (e.g. `int a, b=10; while (b--) { int a; a = 7; }`) will only be flagged with `-Wshadow`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ah, I understand now. Because `Array *array` was inside the `{}` block in the `if`, it's a different scope and that's why it would work. Thanks for the explanation. I fixed my answer.